# running babel es2015 CLI from windows command line without .babelrc

Tags: babeljs

I tried:

```
npm install -g babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
echo 'console.log([1, 2, 3].map(n => n + 1));' > junk.js
babel --preset [es2015] junk.js
```

I get:

```
'console.log([1, 2, 3].map(n = + 1));';
```

If I try the same in https://babeljs.io/repl I get:

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {
  return n + 1;
}));
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I needed:

```
babel --presets C:\Users\kofifus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015 junk.js
```